# How to install dmenu?

Tags: software-installation

So I just installed Ubuntu for the first time and I was trying to install Dmenu, and I opened the `readme.txt` to find this:

> ### Installation
>
> Edit config.mk to match your local setup (dmenu is installed into
>   the /usr/local namespace by default).
>
> Afterwards enter the following command to build and install dmenu
>   (if necessary as root):
>
> ```
> make clean install
> ```

What exactly is this telling me to do?

Comment: Dmenu can be installed with *sudo apt-get install dmenu* or your software center because it's available at the official Ubuntu repository. No need to compile.

Comment: Actually, it's not called dmenu. `Note, selecting 'suckless-tools' instead of 'dmenu'`

Answer (score 9):

It's telling you to make sure `config.mk` has the settings you want. It looks like config.mk has the install path, as well as a few other options that more advanced users may want to tweak.

As CelticWarrior pointed out, you can install dmenu without having to worry about source code with `sudo apt install dmenu` or `sudo apt install suckless-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to know how to install `dmenu` from source code, here's some hint that I tried to install [dmenu2](https://bitbucket.org/melek/dmenu2/src/default/) from source under xubuntu 20.04 focal. Dmenu2 is a patched version of dmenu. Which also works with [dmenu](https://git.suckless.org/dmenu/) of course.

The commands and explanations:

The bitbucket repo of dmenu2 uses mercurial, so...

```
sudo apt install mercurial
```

Check original `dmenu` package details to see from which repository is installed
as mentioned `dmenu` is a virtual package name so look for `suckless-tools`:

```
apt show suckless-tools
```

The interesting line is:

```
APT-Sources: http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

And especially the `universe` repository
Uncomment, if necessary, the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (span your favorite editor)

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The line we are looking for is a `deb-src` for the `universe` repository, it might look like:

```
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
```

update the packages list

```
sudo apt update
```

and let the packaging magic do the rest, this will install all the needed dependencies to build the packages:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep suckless-tools
```

now simply let the build tools do the job:

```
cd path/to/cloned/dmenu
make
```

You should have an fresh compiled `./dmenu` in your local directory.

See inside the `Makefile` the actions that will be performed:

```
install: all
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    cp -f dmenu dmenu_path dmenu_run stest $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/dmenu
    chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/dmenu_path
    chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/dmenu_run
    chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/stest
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(MANPREFIX)/man1
    sed "s/VERSION/$(VERSION)/g" < dmenu.1 > $(DESTDIR)$(MANPREFIX)/man1/dmenu.1
    sed "s/VERSION/$(VERSION)/g" < stest.1 > $(DESTDIR)$(MANPREFIX)/man1/stest.1
    chmod 644 $(DESTDIR)$(MANPREFIX)/man1/dmenu.1
    chmod 644 $(DESTDIR)$(MANPREFIX)/man1/stest.1
```

To finally install it to the destination configured (`PREFIX = /usr/local` in `config.mk`)

```
sudo make install
```

Have fun!

Want even more fun? check [rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi) instead, a drop in replacement for dmenu, and many more.

Which is also packaged already:

```
sudo apt install rofi
ls | rofi -dmenu
```